# Redirecting system() function call using LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c++, c, linux, ld-preload

I want to replace the calls to system() function made by my program using LD_PRELOAD.

So I created the following wrapper functions in a shared library for testing.

```
// syshook.c

int system(const char * command)
{
    printf("system() called for %s ************************************\n", command);
    return 55;
}

char * getenv (const char* name)
{
    printf("my getenv() *********************");
    return 0;
}
```

And compiled and linked to a shared object libsyshook.so with gcc.

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c *.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libsyshook.so -o libsyshook.so.1.0
ln -s libsyshook.so libsyshook.so.1.0
```

However, when I run the program with with LD_PRELOAD as shown below, my wrapper function for system() is not called, but the wrapper for getenv() called.

```
LD_PRELOAD="libsyshook.so" myprog
```

When I attach the debugger, I can see that system() call, calls the implementation in libpthread.so. So why is redirecting system() not working. I don't think there is any limitation on that ??

Edit:
My test program compiled to myprog above looks like this. Comments indicate my observations.

```
void TestClass::testMethod()
{
    string cmdLine = "date";
    if (!mainWin) cmdLine = "time";

    int retFromSys = system(cmdLine.c_str());   // goes into libpthread when stepped in.
    cout << "return from system " << retFromSys << endl; // prints 0, not 55  
    getenv("DEBUG_SYS");  // Wrapper function called for this. Prints "my getenv ****** ..."
```

Comment: Maybe you should use an absolute path, or at least `LD_PRELOAD="./libsyshook.so"`

Comment: Use `strace` to understand what is happenning

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I have already added the path of libsyshook.so to the beginning of $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. In fact, issue is only for system(), I can see the the getenv() wrapper called successfully. So this is not due to path issue.

Comment: Show your working program -by editing your question-, or a small example similar (for that question) to it. Give us the compilation commands and how did you test that.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have edited my post to include the test code and compile command line. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most usual case of bad linking with LD_PRELOAD is when GCC replace your function by another one, when he think it can make your code faster to execute.

For instance, if GCC read this line in your code :

```
printf("%d", strlen("toto"));
```

It will replace with this line before compiling it :

```
puts("4");
```

Because it knows the `printf` and `strlen` functions, and think the output would be the same with `puts` function.

In this example, if you made your own `printf` or `strlen` function in a library loaded with LD_PRELOAD, your function won't be called after compilation, because GCC would have replaced function calls.

I think your problem is for the same reason. `system` is a very heavy function, and GCC may replaced your function call by another. For instance, if you tried :

```
system("ls");
```

GCC might replaced your line by :

```
execlp("ls", "ls");
```

That would do the same, but in less heavy. It couldn't know that you wanted to use your own `system` function. Try to disassemble your code to check if this is the problem.

As solution, I suggest you to try to call `system` with a more "random" parameter, to make GCC think it should not try to replace it. Maybe something like :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* line = NULL;

    // Useless condition to make GCC think the parameter is variable
    if (argc == 1)
        line = "ls";

    return (system(line));
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, `system` is not replaced by optimizing [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). If it was, it cannot be replaced by `execve` but should be replaced by `fork` then `execve` then `waitpid`

Comment: Are you sure about that ? execlp was just an example, some less known functions, like popen, do almost the same thing than system... Especially if the parameter is a single binary name rather than a complex command line.

Comment: Yes, you can check with `strace` or by glancing inside source code of GCC. Indeed `printf` can be optimized (thru `__builtin_printf`) but `system` is declared as a function in `<stdlib.h>` (at least on my Debian/Sid/amd64) and there is no `__builtin_system`

Comment: Ok... Thanks you for clarification so.

Comment: After stepping into system() in assembly mode in my main program, I could see that it is actually a system() implementation in libpthread.so (already mentioned in the original post)
`(gdb) nexti`
`0x000000319840e3b0 in system () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0`
`(gdb) nexti`
`0x0000003198404e58 in __libc_system@plt () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0`
`(gdb) nexti`
`0x000000319783c5d0 in system () from /lib64/libc.so.6`

Comment: Could you try to compile and run the part of your code with `system` call, without linking with the libpthread ?

Comment: @Aracthor Yes ! I wrote a simple program without any specific linking to libpthread. Now my wrapper for system() is getting called !! However, for the original code, I don't have much control over the build environment so I need to get that working. Since libpthread is also calling libc version of system() internally, isn't my wrapper supposed to get called anyway ??

Comment: I still don't understand why your library in LD_PRELOAD is not priority on others... You said you added libsyshook.so at the begin of LD_LIBRARY_PATH... Did you try to add it at the end rather at the begin ? There might be an order importance here.

Comment: @Aracthor Tried appending libsyshook.so path at the end of LD_LIBRARY_PATH, instead of at the beginning. But no luck :-(

Comment: So I'm sorry, But I don't see why your libpthread is called before your libsyshook... By the way, I don't know about your "build environment", so if you cannot access or change it, I don't see how you could use your library.

Comment: Actually the command line I used to invoke my program was `LD_PRELOAD="libsyshook.so" myprog` where `myprog` was a shell script that did actual invocation of the executable, which had a different LD_PRELOAD value at invocation. So I have resolved the issue by putting the correct LD_PRELOAD value there in the script. But I don't understand why only system() was not hooked, while getenv was hooked correctly.

Comment: You should have told that myprog was a shell script and not an executable... I suppose that your shell use an overload of `system` to execute a shell script, so may erase your own version of the function, and this could be why `getenv` worked and not `system`. But I'm not sure of that...

Comment: Yes @Aracthor. I should have told that but the different behaviors for system() and getenv(), made me confused. Thanks for all your feedback.